# Vectors that satisfy Pythagorean Theorem $\|x+y\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

In inner product space $H$ over $\Bbb{C}$, what are the vectors that satisfy  $||x+y||^2=||x||^2+||y||^2$?

I have made many attempts over and over again, trying to show that based on the fact that $$\langle x,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle+\langle x,y\rangle+\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$$ then $\langle x,y\rangle=i\cdot{a}$ for $a\in \Bbb{R}$, not necessarily orthogonal. But is $y=i\cdot r\cdot x$ or $x=i\cdot r\cdot y$? Why can't I seem to go any further as to presenting $x$ as $y$ or $y$ as $x$?

Then I tried to take $\left\langle{ia x\over \|x\|^2}-y,{ia x\over \|x\|^2}-y\right\rangle$ and $\left\langle x-{ia y\over \|y\|^2},x-{ia y\over \|y\|^2}\right\rangle$ with the idea in mind that either $y={xai\over \|x\|^2}$ or $x={yai\over \|y\|^2}$, but there might be too many solutions to that, and I really can't work with the results of this expansion. And I could assume $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ anyway (I think?).

Could you drop me a hint?

Comment: That was a typo, I should have noticed

Comment: Why would you expect to represent $y$ in terms of $x?$ If you knew they were orthogonal, would you be able to represent $y$ in terms of $x?$

Comment: I’m not sure you can do much better than $\langle x,y\rangle$ being imaginary.

Comment: The equation holds if and only if $ \langle x, y \rangle$ has real part $0$ (or $ \langle x, y \rangle =ia$ with $a$ real) and you cannot do anything more with this.

Comment: You are right about that case, but can such vectors be non-orthogonal and satisfy this equality? For instance, if the product $<x,y>$ is imaginary and the two conjugate terms cancel each other out, their product not being zero, what can allow me to say I have defined all such vectors as required?

Comment: You can say that $y-iax$ must be orthogonal to $x$ for some real $a.$ No reason to divide bt $\|x\|^2,$ which only complicates things.

Comment: By definition, orthogonal means that $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$, so the conclusion is that $\lVert x + y\rVert^2 = \lVert x\rVert^2 + \lVert y \rVert^2$ does not imply that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. you left off the squares in that equality.

Comment: Yes, but only retrospectively.